Problemas con el error Cuadrático Medio Python y resultado erróneo
Tengo un problema con el codigo pero no se por que esta mal
me da Error cuadrático medio: 350300585341330.44 y una
Fecha de descomposición estimada para el banco BU0964: [1.67597605e+18] No se por que me da este resultado soy nuevo en el modelado, saben que es lo que esta mal? o deberia cambiar de libreria? ya que los datos que manejo son string y date, no se si eso afecte, eh visto videos y paginas y no muestran datos similares solo datos numericos aqui un ejemplo de los datos
Banco
BU0964,
BU0729,
BU3572
Fecha 2021-12-31, 2022-01-01, 2022-01-01
aqui parte del codigo
datos['BancoN'] = datos['Banco'].apply(lambda x: ord(x[0])*1000 + ord(x[1]))

datos['Fecha'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['Fecha'])

X = datos['BancoN'].values.reshape(-1, 1) 
y = datos['Fecha']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

Creo que esto es lo que esta mal
y_test_converted = pd.to_datetime(y_test)
y_test_converted = y_test.astype(int) // 10**9
y_pred_converted = y_pred.astype(int) // 10**9
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test_converted, y_pred_converted)
print("Error cuadrático medio:", mse)

Y aqui inserto un dato y lo imprime
banco_nuevo = 'BU0964'
banco_nuevo = ord(banco_nuevo[0])*1000 + ord(banco_nuevo[1])
fecha_prediccion = model.predict([[banco_nuevo]])
print("Fecha de descomposición estimada para el banco {}: {}".format(banco_nuevo, fecha_prediccion))

y me devuelve esto
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.25.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.3.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.11.4)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=1.1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from scikit-learn) (3.4.0)
Error cuadrático medio: 350300585341330.44
Fecha de descomposición estimada para el banco BU0964: [1.67597605e+18]
